# Simple Linked List that holds an int

Tags: c++, beginner, linked-list

I am inexperienced in C++.  I was able to get my `LinkedList` to be fully functional.  I was hoping to get some feedback as to whether or not I followed bad practices and if there are any risks associated with my code.

**LinkedList.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

#include "Node.h"

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node *head;
    int count;
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    int get_count();
    void AddNode(int);
    std::string GetList();
    bool Contains(int);
    void Remove(int);
    int GetValue(int);
};
```

**LinkedList.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    head = new Node(0);
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
}

int LinkedList::get_count(){
    return count;
}

void LinkedList::AddNode(int _value){
    Node *node = new Node(_value);
    Node *previousNode = head;
    while (previousNode->next_node && previousNode->next_node->get_value() <= node->get_value()){
        previousNode = previousNode->next_node;
    }
    if (previousNode->next_node){
        node->next_node = previousNode->next_node;
    }
    previousNode->next_node = node;
    count++;
}

std::string LinkedList::GetList(){
    std::string list;
    Node *currentNode = head;
    while (currentNode->next_node){
        currentNode = currentNode->next_node;
        list += std::to_string(currentNode->get_value()) + " ";
    }
    return list;
}

bool LinkedList::Contains(int number){
    Node *currentNode = head;
    while (currentNode->next_node){
        currentNode = currentNode->next_node;
        if (currentNode->get_value() == number){
            return true;
        }
        if (currentNode->get_value() > number){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void LinkedList::Remove(int number){
    Node *previousNode = head;
    Node *currentNode = head;
    while (currentNode->next_node){
        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode->next_node;
        if (currentNode->get_value() == number){
            previousNode->next_node = currentNode->next_node;
            delete currentNode;
            count--;
            return;
        }
    }
}

int LinkedList::GetValue(int index){
    Node *currentNode = head;
    int currentIndex = -1;
    while (currentNode->next_node){
        currentNode = currentNode->next_node;
        currentIndex++;
        if (index == currentIndex){
            return currentNode->get_value();
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Node.h**

```
#pragma once

class Node
{
private:
    int value;
public:
    Node(int);
    ~Node();
    Node *next_node;
    int get_value();
    void set_value(int);
};
```

**Node.cpp**

```
#include "Node.h"

Node::Node(int _value)
{
    value = _value;
}

Node::~Node()
{
}

int Node::get_value(){
    return value;
}
void Node::set_value(int _value){
    value = _value;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Instead of having `Node` use getters and setters, just make it a `struct` declared within the `private` section of `LinkedList`.  It won't need its own files, either.
- All but one of your functions are in PascalCase.  Whether you choose that or camelCase, choose just one and maintain that.  This should be kept consistent.
- When creating a new linked list, the head should first point to `NULL` (or `nullptr` in C++11) to indicate an empty list.  You're instead having the head point to a new node, so the list isn't really considered empty at the start.
- You have an empty destructor, even though you allocate memory with `new`.  In order to prevent memory leaks, the destructor should use `delete` on each allocated `Node`.  This is typically done with a loop through the list.
- Member functions that don't modify data members should be `const`.  This also prevents any accidental modifications to data members within these functions.

  An example with your `get_count()` function:

  ```
  int LinkedList::get_count() const {
      return count;
  }
  ```

Comment: I followed the naming conventions at http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Function_Names.  It says regular functions are LikeThis() and getters setters are like_this().  Or did I misunderstand it?  Or is that intended to be an either or?

Comment: @Evorlor: It's usually either one of them.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the excellent suggestions by @Jamal...

**Physical Layout of class**

The `public` section of a class should appear first, followed by the `protected` section, and `private` section should appear last. The reason for that is that to the users of the class, the `public` section of a class is its most visible interface, the `protected` section is the next visible interface, and the `private` section is the least visible interface.

```
class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList();

    ...

private:
    Node *head;
    int count;
};
```

**Logic error in LinkedList::Remove**

The posted code does not take into account the possibility that the given input corresponds to the `head` of the list.

```
void LinkedList::Remove(int number){
    Node *previousNode = head;
    Node *currentNode = head;

    // You need this.
    if ( head->get_value() == number )
    {
        Node* temp = head->next_node;
        delete head;
        head = temp;
        return;
    }

    while (currentNode->next_node){
        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode->next_node;
        if (currentNode->get_value() == number){
            previousNode->next_node = currentNode->next_node;
            delete currentNode;
            count--;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most important points have already been said. But here are some minor things:

**Portability**

`#pragma once` is actually non standard, thus you should consider using usual include guards if you want to support ExoticCompilerFoo.

**Trailing whitespace**

Your `GetList` function puts an extra whitespace at the end of the list, though you might already know this.

**Utility function**

Your `GetList` function could actually be implemented using only the public interface of your class. It could also be used with other classes sharing that public interface. Thus you could actually write it as a generic freestanding function.

This is, for example, what the standard library does with its algorithms.